# Conceptual Schema for Pods CMS?

Tags: wordpress, database-schema, podscms

Is there a way to view the conceptual schema for a database setup using WordPress with the Pods CMS plugin?  I have inherited a database using this setup and would like to be able to see all the relationships in a graphical form.  PhpMyAdmin can't see the relational schema as all the relationships are stored in a Pods specific table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a great idea, if you'd like this to be added (a printable schema of Pods and their relationships) please go to https://github.com/sc0ttkclark/pods/issues/new and suggest that new feature. Otherwise, you're more than welcome to go to WP Admin >> Pods >> Setup >> and browse each pod's fields to see where things relate to.